# Using the value of a string variable as object parameter accessor

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, accessor

I am attempting to dynamically access an object with a property value that is contained within a string. Example below:

```
var toolState = {
    draw_point: false;
    draw_line: false;
}

var dynamicText = "draw_point";

toolState.dynamicText = true; //here is the problem
```

I'm fairly new to JS. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Thanks

Comment: Try `toolState[dynamicText]`.

Comment: toolState[dynamicText] or toolState["propertyName"]

Comment: And [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/218196) and probably [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dynamic+property+variable)

Comment: I recommend to read [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation instead of dot notation for variable names as properties.

```
toolState[dynamicText] = true;
```